# Why is the content of the tag and category button not visible when creating a post in laravel?

Tags: laravel, blogs

I try to create blog web page in laravel. While creating the post, the contents of the tag and category button are not visible.

My post.blade.php;

```html
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('headSection')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/plugins/select2/select2.min.css') }}">
@endsection
@section('main-content')
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
      Text Editors
      <small>Advanced form element</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
      <li class="active">Editors</li>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
        <div class="box box-primary">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Titles</h3>
          </div>
          @include('includes.messages')
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <!-- form start -->
          <form role="form" action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Post Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="subtitle">Post Sub Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtitle" name="subtitle" placeholder="Sub Title">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="slug">Post Slug</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Slug">
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <br>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                  <label for="image">File input</label>
                                  <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1"> Publish
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:18px;">
                                <label>Select Tags</label>
                                <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="tags[]">
                                @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                                  <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:18px;">
                                <label>Select Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="categories[]">
                                  @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            
            <div class="box">
             <div class="box-header">
               <h3 class="box-title">Write Post Body Here
                 <small>Simple and fast</small>
               </h3>
               <!-- tools box -->
               <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                   <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /. tools -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.box-header -->
               <div class="box-body pad">
                 <textarea name="body" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;" id="editor1"></textarea>
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="box-footer">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <a href='{{ route('post.index') }}' class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->

        
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-->
    </div>
    <!-- ./row -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
@endsection
@section('footerSection')
<script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{  asset('admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
      // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
      // instance, using default configuration.
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2();
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

I am stuck because everytime I submit a post with tags and category.
My edit blade.php file;

```html
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('headSection')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/plugins/select2/select2.min.css') }}">
@endsection
@section('main-content')
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
      Text Editors
      <small>Advanced form element</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
      <li class="active">Editors</li>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
        <div class="box box-primary">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Titles</h3>
          </div>
          @include('includes.messages')
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <!-- form start -->
          <form role="form" action="{{ route('post.update',$post->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Post Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $post->title }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="subtitle">Post Sub Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtitle" name="subtitle" placeholder="Sub Title" value="{{ $post->subtitle }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="slug">Post Slug</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Slug" value="{{ $post->slug }}">
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <label for="image">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" @if ($post->status == 1)
                        {{'checked'}}
                      @endif> Publish
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:18px;">
                  <label>Select Tags</label>
                  <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="tags[]">
                    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                    <option value="{{ $tag->id }}"
                      @foreach ($post->tags as $postTag)
                        @if ($postTag->id == $tag->id)
                          selected
                        @endif
                      @endforeach
                    >{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:18px;">
                  <label>Select Category</label>
                  <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" name="categories[]">
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}"
                    @foreach ($post->categories as $postCategory)
                      @if ($postCategory->id == $category->id)
                        selected
                      @endif
                    @endforeach
                    >{{ $category->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            
            <div class="box">
             <div class="box-header">
               <h3 class="box-title">Write Post Body Here
                 <small>Simple and fast</small>
               </h3>
               <!-- tools box -->
               <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                   <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /. tools -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.box-header -->
               <div class="box-body pad">
                <textarea name="body" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;" id="editor1">{{ $post->body }}</textarea>
              </div>
             </div>

             <div class="box-footer">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <a href='{{ route('post.index') }}' class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->

        
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-->
    </div>
    <!-- ./row -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
@endsection
@section('footerSection')
<script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{  asset('admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
      // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
      // instance, using default configuration.
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
      //bootstrap WYSIHTML5 - text editor
      $(".textarea").wysihtml5();
    });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2();
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

My show blade php file;

```html
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('headSection')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('main-content')
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
      Blank page
      <small>it all starts here</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
      <li class="active">Blank page</li>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <section class="content">

    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Title</h3>
        
          <a class='col-lg-offset-5 btn btn-success' href="{{ route('post.create') }}">Add New</a>
        
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                      <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                      <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>S.No</th>
                          <th>Title</th>
                          <th>Sub Title</th>
                          <th>Slug</th>
                          <th>Creatd At</th>
                          <th>Edit</th>
                          <th>Delete</th>
                          
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($posts as $post)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->subtitle }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->slug }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>

                            
                              <td><a href="{{ route('post.edit',$post->id) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                            

                            
                            <td>
                              <form id="delete-form-{{ $post->id }}" method="post" action="{{ route('post.destroy',$post->id) }}" style="display: none">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                              </form>
                              <a href="" onclick="
                              if(confirm('Are you sure, You Want to delete this?'))
                                  {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    document.getElementById('delete-form-{{ $post->id }}').submit();
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                  }" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                            </td>
                          
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                          <th>S.No</th>
                          <th>Title</th>
                          <th>Sub Title</th>
                          <th>Slug</th>
                          <th>Creatd At</th>
                          
                          <th>Edit</th>
                          
                           
                          <th>Delete</th>
                          
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                  </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      <div class="box-footer">
        Footer
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-footer-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->

  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
@endsection
@section('footerSection')
<script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('admin/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

My PostController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\user\category;
use App\Model\user\post;
use App\Model\user\tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = post::all();
        return view('admin.post.show',compact('posts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $tags =tag::all();
        $categories =category::all();
        return view('admin.post.post',compact('tags','categories'));
    
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        return $request->all();
        $this->validate($request,[

            'title'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            'slug'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required',

        ]);

        $post = new post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->save();
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);

        return redirect(route('post.index'));

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post= post::where('id',$id)->first();
        $tags =tag::all();
        $categories =category::all();
        return view('admin.post.edit',compact('tags','categories','post'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {


        $this->validate($request,[

            'title'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            'slug'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required',

        ]);

        $post = post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        $post->save();

        return redirect(route('post.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        post::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

My tagcontroller.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\user\tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TagController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tags = tag::all();
        return view('admin.tag.show',compact('tags'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.tag.tag');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',

        ]);

        $tag = new tag;
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->slug = $request->slug;
        $tag->save();


        return redirect(route('tag.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $tag= tag::where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('admin.tag.edit',compact('tag'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',

        ]);

        $tag = tag::find($id);
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->slug = $request->slug;
        $tag->save();


        return redirect(route('tag.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        tag::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

My categorycontroller.php;

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\user\category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = category::all();
        return view('admin.category.show',compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.category.category');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',

        ]);

        $category = new category;
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = $request->slug;
        $category->save();


        return redirect(route('category.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $category= category::where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('admin.category.edit',compact('category'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',

        ]);

        $category = category::find($id);
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = $request->slug;
        $category->save();


        return redirect(route('category.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        category::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? And furthermore how can i do it?

Comment: Please provide us your controller code. e.g. where you are setting the variable `$tags`

Comment: I add it the postcontroller.php

Comment: I add it also tag and category controller.